# Building and Filtering a Cartesian Product Collection(Custom Objects) With Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Slot Slot { get; set; }
    public List<string> Spells { get; set; }
}
```

Slot is an enumeration:

```
public enum Slot
{
    Necklace = 1,
    Ring = 2,
    Bracelet = 3
}
```

The end Cartesian product I'm looking for is all possible combination of items fitting in to the 
 a collection of the following object type:

```
public class Set
{
    public int Necklace { get; set; }
    public int LeftBrace { get; set; }
    public int RightBrace { get; set; }
    public int LeftRing { get; set; }
    public int RightRing { get; set; }
}
```

- Each item can only be used once per set.
- Each int property in the Set refers to Item.Id
- Items can only fit into the specified slot and cannot be added multiple times to a set.
- If a set contains duplicate spells over multiple items, it should not be added to the Cartesian product or if that is not possible, filtered out of the resulting enumeration.
- Spells on items can be a minimum of one and maximum of four and are never duplicated on the item itself.

Here are the collections I'm getting to build the Cartesian product. Each of these is derived from the main list of Items:

```
var _neckItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot.Contains(Slot.Necklace)).ToArray();
var _leftRingItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot.Contains(Slot.Ring)).ToArray();
var _rightRingItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot.Contains(Slot.Ring)).ToArray();
var _leftBraceItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot.Contains(Slot.Bracelet)).ToArray();
var _rightBraceItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot.Contains(Slot.Bracelet)).ToArray();
```

Here is how I am setting up the Cartesian product:

```
Item[][] items = {
    _neckItems,
    _leftRingItems,
    _rightRingItems,
    _leftBraceItems
};

var sets = CartesianHelper.CartesianProduct(items);
```

And here is the Cartesian method itself:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

Here is how I am projecting the enumeration to sets:

```
var projectedSets = from s in sets.GroupBy(s => s.SelectMany(ss => ss.Spells).Distinct()).Select(x => x.First())
    where s.ToArray()[1].Id != s.ToArray()[2].Id
    && s.ToArray()[3].Id != s.ToArray()[4].Id
    select new Set
    {
        Necklace = s.ToArray()[0].Id,
        LeftRing = s.ToArray()[1].Id,
        RightRing = s.ToArray()[2].Id,
        LeftBrace = s.ToArray()[3].Id,
        RightBrace = s.ToArray()[4].Id,
    };
```

So overall this is a good start and I am seeing results. However, when I add more than two collections to the Cartesian product, the results are increasing exponentially and the app becomes non responsive.

There's something wrong with my linq query grouping as it's not filtering out duplicate spells in sets and maybe it's best to modify the Cartesian method before getting to that point.

One final condition I would like to have is being able to consider empty slots in any given set. The end goal is to determine the maximum amount of covered slots given a set list of items. Also should note, the slots I listed above are actually only 3 of 15 in the final solution.

edit - I should clarify that the end result is the maximum number of covered slots AND the maximum number of unique spells given a set of items.

Thanks for any insight and help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the steps I follow to perform the cartesian product of an arbitrary number of array of integers.

Let's say we have the five arrays below:

```
  var items1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
  var items2 = new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8};
  var items3 = new int[]{9, 10, 11, 12};
  var items4 = new int[]{13, 14, 15, 16};
  var items5 = new int[]{17, 18, 19, 20};
```

And let's say we have the `Set` class which will contain an element of the cartesian product:

```
// I named the property like this to allow further manipulation afterward
class Set
{
  public int Item_1 { get; set; }
  public int Item_2 { get; set; } 
  public int Item_3 { get; set; }
  public int Item_4 { get; set; }
  public int Item_5 { get; set; }
}
```

As such, adding an array will require us to add another property to the `Set` class. Assuming it is no big deal, let's move on to the next step.

To perform cartesian product of these five arrays manually, we can do as follow:

**Method 1: using Linq query expression**

```
 var cp1 = 
    from i1 in items1
    from i2 in items2
    from i3 in items3
    from i4 in items4
    from i5 in items5
    select new Set
    {
      Item_1 = i1,
      Item_2 = i2,
      Item_3 = i3,
      Item_4 = i4,
      Item_5 = i5
    };
```

Most of the time, this is enough to perform a cartesian product, but adding another collection to the operation would require a change to the query. So, let's say we have the requirement to create a cartesian product query that will work for any number of collections we pass to it. Before implementing this method, let's see how we can achieve the above query using lambda expressions:

**Method 2: manually but using lambda expressions**

```
 var cp2 = items1.SelectMany(
    i1 => items2.SelectMany(
    i2 => items3.SelectMany(
    i3 => items4.SelectMany(
    i4 => items5.Select(
    i5 => new Set
    {
      Item_1 = i1,
      Item_2 = i2,
      Item_3 = i3,
      Item_4 = i4,
      Item_5 = i5
    })))));
```

Once again, it works but adding another collection to the operation would require changing the query. But, what's interesting about this one is the way we chain the `SelectMany` method recursively. Since basically Linq works with expression trees, we can build dynamically the expression tree of the previous query in order to implement the cartesian product of an arbitrary number of arrays:

**Method 3: Build the expression tree dynamically**

```
MethodCallExpression CartesianProductExpression(int[][] items)
{
  var pes = new List<ParameterExpression>();
  return BuildExpression(items, pes, items.Length);
}

MethodCallExpression BuildExpression(int[][] items, List<ParameterExpression> pes, int numberOfArray)
{
  var queryable = items[0].AsQueryable<int>();
  ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), $"i{pes.Count+1}");
  pes.Add(pe);

  if(pes.Count == numberOfArray)
  {
    NewExpression newTripleExpression = Expression.New(typeof(Set));
    MemberBinding[] bindings = new MemberBinding[pes.Count];
    var index = 0;
    foreach(var p in pes)
    {
      bindings[index++] = SetBindings.GetBinding($"Item_{index}", p);
    }
    Expression selectBody = Expression.MemberInit(newTripleExpression, bindings);
    return Expression.Call(
      typeof(Queryable),
      "Select",
      new Type[] { queryable.ElementType, typeof(Set) },
      queryable.Expression,
      Expression.Lambda<Func<int, Set>>(selectBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
  }

  return Expression.Call(
      typeof(Queryable),
      "SelectMany",
      new Type[] { queryable.ElementType, typeof(Set) },
      queryable.Expression,
      Expression.Lambda<Func<int, IEnumerable<Set>>>(BuildExpression(items.Skip(1).ToArray(), pes, numberOfArray), new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
}

// ... In another class file
static class SetBindings
{
  public static MemberBinding GetBinding(string propertyName, ParameterExpression pe)
  {
    MemberInfo member = typeof(Set).GetMember(propertyName)[0];
    return Expression.Bind(member, pe);
  }
}
```

This method can be used as follow:

```
int[][] items = new int[][] {items1, items2, items3, items4, items5};
var queryable = items[0].AsQueryable<int>();
var expression = CartesianProductExpression(items);
IQueryable<Set> cp3 = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Set>(expression);
```

We this method, adding another array would only involve adding another property to the `Set` class.

This is how the result looks like in Linqpad:[image]

So, back to your question, you may interpolate this solution to your use case. For example, instead of:

```
var _neckItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot == Slot.Necklace).ToArray();
\\...
```

You can directly project to `Id` as follow:

```
var _neckItems = _filterList.Where(i => i.Slot == Slot.Necklace).Select(i => i.Id).ToArray()
//...
```

Then use one of the above methods.